# Inference question through LoRA in Whisper model

Tags: transformer-model, whisper

I trained Whisper model through LoRA.
But there's a problem.

The original model directory I trained has a capacity of 2.7G.
However, the size of the model directory learned through LoRA is 57M.

From this, I found that only additional weighting information was save to the LoRA directory.
(That is, the original weighting information is not included.)

Therefore, this is a question.
How can I combine the existing Whisper model with a model trained with LoRA for Inference?

Below, I'm attaching my code for your convenience.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq, AutoProcessor, pipeline
from peft import PeftModel, PeftConfig

class whisper:
    # model_str
    # 1. large - "openai/whisper-large-v3"
    # 2. medium - "openai/whisper-medium"
    # 3. small - "openai/whisper-small"
    def __init__(self, baseModelPath):
        device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
        torch_dtype = torch.float16 if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.float32
        
        
        model = AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq.from_pretrained(baseModelPath, torch_dtype=torch_dtype, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, use_safetensors=True)
        model.to(device)

        processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(baseModelPath)

        self.pipe = pipeline(
        "automatic-speech-recognition",
        model=model,
        tokenizer=processor.tokenizer,
        feature_extractor=processor.feature_extractor,
        max_new_tokens=128,
        chunk_length_s=30,
        batch_size=16,
        return_timestamps=True,
        torch_dtype=torch_dtype,
        device=device,
        )

        
    # korean
    def getText(self, audioPath, language='<|ko|>'):
        sentence = self.pipe(audioPath, generate_kwargs={"task":"transcribe", "language":language})
        return sentence['text']
```

There is some information related to [that link](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/en/tutorials/using_peft_for_inference), but I don't know if it can be applied to the Whisper model.

Below are the files in the original directory.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   34K Mar  4 17:49 added_tokens.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1.4K Mar  5 09:48 config.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3.0K Mar  5 09:48 generation_config.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  483K Mar  4 17:49 merges.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  923M Mar  5 09:48 model.safetensors
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   52K Mar  4 17:49 normalizer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1.8G Mar  5 09:49 optimizer.pt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   339 Mar  5 09:48 preprocessor_config.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14K Mar  5 09:49 rng_state.pth
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4.0K Mar  4 17:49 runs
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1.1K Mar  5 09:49 scheduler.pt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2.2K Mar  4 17:49 special_tokens_map.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  277K Mar  4 17:49 tokenizer_config.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   60K Mar  5 09:49 trainer_state.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4.9K Mar  5 09:48 training_args.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1013K Mar  4 17:49 vocab.json
```

Below are the files in the LoRA-processed directory for the original files.

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4.0K Mar 21 06:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4.0K Mar 21 13:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5.0K Mar 21 06:13 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   789 Mar 21 06:13 adapter_config.json
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4.0K Mar 21 06:13 adapter_model
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14M Mar 21 06:13 adapter_model.safetensors
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   34K Mar 20 12:55 added_tokens.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  483K Mar 20 12:55 merges.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   52K Mar 20 12:55 normalizer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   28M Mar 21 06:13 optimizer.pt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   339 Mar 21 06:13 preprocessor_config.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14K Mar 21 06:13 rng_state.pth
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1.1K Mar 21 06:13 scheduler.pt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2.2K Mar 20 12:55 special_tokens_map.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  277K Mar 20 12:55 tokenizer_config.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   31K Mar 21 06:13 trainer_state.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4.9K Mar 21 06:13 training_args.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1013K Mar 20 12:55 vocab.json
```